Eisenbud & Harris 'The Geometry of Schemes', Proposition II-29 - flatness of a map to a regular 1-dimensional scheme
I'm stuck on the inference (c)$\Leftrightarrow$(a) in the following proposition:
Let $B=\operatorname{Spec}R$ be a regular, one-dimensional scheme, $0\in B$ a closed point and $B^{*}=B\backslash \{0\}$ Let $\mathscr{X}\subseteq \textbf{A}^{n}_{R}$ be a closed subscheme and $\pi : \mathscr{X} \rightarrow B$ the projection, $\mathscr{X}^{*}=\pi^{-1}(B^{*})$. Then the following are equivalent
(a) $\pi$ is flat over $0$
(b) $\lim_{b\to 0}X_{b}=X_{0}$, or, phrased alternatively, $\overline{\mathscr{X}^{*}}=\mathscr{X}$
(c) No irreducible or embedded component is contained in $X_{0}$

This boils down to the following two facts:

If $R$ is a ring and $M$ an $R$-module, then $M$ is flat over $R$ iff $I\otimes_R M\to M$ is injective for all finitely-generated ideals $I\subset R$. In the case of a ring map $\varphi:R\to A$ for $R$ a DVR with uniformizer $z$, the homomorphism $\varphi$ is flat iff $\varphi(z)$ is not a zero-divisor.
The generic points of irreducible components or embedded components are precisely the associated points, i.e. the points $x\in X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ has maximal ideal consisting entirely of nilpotent elements. To check that no irreducible or embedded component is contained in $X_0$, it is equivalent to show that no associated point of $X$ maps to $0$.

Suppose $\pi$ is flat. Let $x\in X$ be a point with (set-theoretic) image $0\in B$, and let $z\in\mathcal{O}_{B,0}$ be a uniformizer. Then $\mathcal{O}_{B,0}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is flat, so the image of $z$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is not a zero-divisor and hence $x$ is not an associated point of $X$. But the generic points of irreducible and embedded components are both associated points - therefore (a) implies (c).
Conversely, suppose no associated point of $X$ maps to $0$. We're on the hook for showing that $z$, the uniformizer of $\mathcal{O}_{B,0}$, is not a zero-divisor in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for every $x\in X$ mapping to $0\in B$. If the image of $z$ is a zero-divisor, then it is contained in an associated prime $p$ of $(0)\subset\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, so the point $x'\in X$ corresponding to $p\subset\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is an associated point of $X$ mapping to $0$, violating our assumptions. Therefore the image of $z$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is not a zero-divisor and so $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is flat over $\mathcal{O}_{B,0}$ and we've won.
